# Implication of Memoryless Property of Geometric Distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, stochastic-calculus

My question arises from the proof of the following result.

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two independent random variables, where $X$ has a geometric distribution and $Y$ takes only integer values. Then
    \begin{equation}\label{memoryless}
  \boldsymbol{\operatorname{P}}(X-Y>n|X>Y) = \boldsymbol{\operatorname{P}}(X>n),
  \end{equation}
for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

At one step of the proof, the author concludes that it follows from the memoryles property
    \begin{equation*}
 \boldsymbol{\operatorname{P}}(X-n=k|X>n) = \boldsymbol{\operatorname{P}}(X=k),
 \end{equation*}
for all $k,n \in \mathbb{N}$ that 
    \begin{equation*}
 \boldsymbol{\operatorname{P}}(X-Y=k|X>Y) = \boldsymbol{\operatorname{P}}(X=k).
 \end{equation*}

Here the integer $n$ is replaces by the random variable $Y$. Why is it the case that this can be done? It seems obvious but how can you argue that this implication is true? When considering how the memoryless property is shown, that is by the calculation

\begin{align}
\boldsymbol{\operatorname{P}}(X-n>k|X>n) &= \frac{\boldsymbol{\operatorname{P}}(X>k+n,X>k)}{\boldsymbol{\operatorname{P}}(X>n)} \\ &=\frac{\boldsymbol{\operatorname{P}}(X>k+n)}{\boldsymbol{\operatorname{P}}(X>k)} \\ &= \frac{(1-p)^{k+n}}{(1-p)^k} \\ &= (1-p)^k \\ &=\boldsymbol{\operatorname{P}}(X>k),
\end{align}

it is not obvious to me how the third equality can hold, when $n$ is replaced by $Y$.

I would appreciate if you could help me clarifying this.

Comment: Do you understand the second = sign in the answer you accepted? I do not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because $Y$ only take values in integers, it holds $$\begin{align*} P(X−Y>k|X>Y) &= \sum_{n\in\Bbb N} P(X−Y>k, Y=n|X>Y) \\ &= \sum_{n\in\Bbb N} P(X - n > k, Y=n | X > n) \\  &=\sum_{n\in\Bbb N}P(X-n>k|X>n)P(Y=n) \\ &= \sum_{n\in\Bbb N}P(X=k)P(Y=n) \\ &= \sum_{n\in\Bbb N}P(X=k,Y=n) \\ &= P(X=k)\end{align*}$$

Where the third and fifth equality holds by independency assumption of $X$ and $Y$.

Comment: thanks, that indeed clarifies it!

Comment: Why does the identity $$P(X−Y>k, Y=n|X>Y) = P(X - n > k, Y=n | X > n)$$ hold? The LHS is $$P(X−n>k, Y=n|X>Y) =\frac{P(X−n>k, Y=n)}{P(X>Y)}$$ while the RHS is $$\frac{P(X−n>k, Y=n)}{P(X>n)}$$ Additionally, note that $P(X−Y>k|X>Y)=P(X>k)$, not $P(X=k)$.

Comment: @alex Ouch! Now, the trouble is to know how you would justify the identity $$P(X-Y>k\mid X>Y)=\sum_nP(X-Y>k\mid X>Y,Y=n)$$ (which seems quite wrong), the identity $$P(X-Y>k\mid X>Y,Y=n)=P(X-Y>k,Y=n\mid X>n)$$ (which seems quite wrong as well), and the identities $$P(X-Y>k\mid X>Y,Y=n)=P(X-Y>k\mid X>n)=P(X-Y>k,Y=n\mid X>n)$$ (which seem even more wrong). This is no excuse for Gono's silence but no, your last comment does not help... In this context, I find also difficult to understand why you *accepted* this answer (if the two upvotes misled you, too bad). :-)

Comment: Indeed, this was a bad answer. But cannot fix it because it was accepted.